# why is paraproduct or paradifferential calculus important in PDE theory?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

In the article https://www.baidu.com/link?url=W1BjGmDoZM8QkrV_Qd_26vzNhCJGWyfH79q5cn7q0QQxomVLtH7Fw_mApElkfCZUWiDcYjNhoLhMrGFEXtf4O_&wd=&eqid=a93906890002f93700000003577cbb98, it says that "...paraproducts have played a central role in analysis and PDEs..." In what sense and how does the development of the paradifferential calculus influence the modern analysis of PDEs? And how does the development of analysis of PDEs influence the paradifferential calculus theory?

I know one example, Danchin's work on the existence of smooth solutions for Navier-Stokes equations in critical spaces (Danchin R. Global existence in critical spaces for compressible Navier-Stokes equations[J]. Inventiones Mathematicae, 2000, 141(3): 579-614.). But I am not familiar with the other examples.

Answer (score 7):

> How does the development of paradifferential calculus influence the modern analysis of PDEs?

You can get a quick glance by looking at [Bony's 1981 paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=631751) with its 476 citations on MathSciNet. (Also, the few sentences after those which you quoted in the article you linked to gave already several broad applications that are extremely useful in PDEs.)

One item *not* on that list, however, is [Hormander's 1990 paper on Nash-Moser Implicit Function Theorem](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1039355), from which we can quote:

> The Nash-Moser method contains constructions which very much resemble the dyadic decompositions which are central in the paradifferential calculus of Bony. In fact, we show that the Nash-Moser technique can often be replaced by elementary nonlinear functional analysis combined with the paradifferential calculus of Bony.

In terms of paraproducts, I think [Tao's lecture notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes6.pdf) give a fairly accurate account of how many PDE people actually think about paraproducts: as a particular way of exposing structures arising from interactions of different frequencies in a product; these structures can then be coupled with knowledge of the linearized evolution to get sharper estimates.

Comment: I'm reading Bony's paper and Tao's notes. But I want to know more on how these tools are applied to PDEs such as Navier-Stokes equations and nonlinear Schrodinger equations.'

Comment: Well, they help in proving estimates :-) I am less familiar with the fluids literature, but for NLS you can find examples in Tao's _Nonlinear Dispersive Equations_ book (section 3.9 concerning Almost Conservation Laws is one). In some contexts you are almost forced into using paraproduct estimates. For example, given two $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ functions you can easily say that their product is in $W^{1,3/2}$ by noticing that Holder estimate gives $$ \| fg\|_{3/2} \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_6 $$ and using the Leibniz rule and Sobolev embedding $H^1 \to L^6$.

Comment: But when you are dealing with fractional Sobolev spaces $H^s$ with $s\not\in\mathbb{N}$, you no longer can use Leibniz rule to pass derivatives to the factors. So if you are trying to run an iteration argument to construct solutions to a nonlinear PDE, and you are working in a fractional Sobolev space, you most likely have to use paraproducts. This is a basic case but there are other applications.